# There's Lombok annotation @Slf4j which won't work

Tags: java, intellij-idea, slf4j, lombok

I need your help. I have a problem with Lombock annotation @Slf4j. When I try to use it I don't have ability to use its functionality:
[image]

There's my build.gradle file:
[image]

I've already installed Lombock into my IntelliJ Idea and enabled Annotating processing, but it haven't got me resul yet.
Can you make some advice? I would be very grateful!

Comment: In addition to having the Lombok plugin installed, also make sure that the "Enable annotation processing" checkbox is ticked under:

Preferences > Compiler > Annotation Processors
Note: starting with IntelliJ 2017, the "Enable Annotation Processing" checkbox has moved to:

Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Annotation Processors

Comment: @scala231 Do not post code lines as image. This makes for the helpers hard to help.

Comment: it works just fine. Do the other generated parts work?

Answer (score 5):

Taking a wild stab here, but lombok doesn't *include* `slf4j`. It really can't do that<sup>1</sup>. All features in the `extern` packages work like this, and it is why the `lombok.extern` package layer exists: To show you that it's a lombok feature that makes some non-core ('external') dependency work nicer, not that the lombok feature includes this dependency or replaces it.

Thus, all you would need to fix this is to add slf4j to your dependencies:

```
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j:1.7.31'
```

omr something along those lines. Note that SLF4j also needs runtime configuration (slf4j itself is just a 'frontend' that lets you write log statements that go to whereever your configuration says they go at runtime. This 'configuration' includes the code to actually do stuff with these logs. Slf4j tutorials will cover all this.

[1] Adding the deps automatically is not really possible; lombok ships with a number of features that are specifically to make some library / framework easier to use, we (DISCLAIMER: I do quite a bit of work on lombok) can't ship them **all of those** as deps of lombok, and we haven't (and probably would never) try to hack into your build system to make some sort of semi-dependent system where we detect you use e.g. `@Slf4j` and somehow make your build system include it only then.

Comment: indeed, specific real problem may have been that slf4j dependency must be defined.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I have been looking for this for sooo long

Answer (score -1):

There is some IDE build issue you have.

Why don't you adopt Maven (or Gradle) build tool, that is used in maybe 80% (gradle is maybe other 19.99%) team projects.

And then there is nothing specific about using Lombock
https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven

just

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.20</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And it works in any IDEA or most IDE

P.S. Specifically no configuration/plugin in IDEA since v2020.3
https://projectlombok.org/setup/intellij

P.P.S. If you use maven/gradle and have any issues in any IDE,
try first to make sure, that there is no issues with build itself by running in command line

```
mvn package
```

or

```
gradle build
```

And then if build is OK, try to resolve specific IDE issue.
Think like "what most people do or won't do to make it work"

For example you can install one more the newest IDEA instance, e.g. IDEA CE (that it undervalued, as it is free) and open your project there: it should just work without any dancing.

Comment: This advice makes no sense. "Please use gradle or maven" - except the question includes gradle (and was last edited _before_ you wrote this answer). Perhaps you didn't fully read the question? None of this seems in any way relevant to the problem OP is having.